# Spring root WebApplicationContext for Servlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a webapp that uses SpringMVC DispatcherServlet to load a WebApplicationContext. The Spring reference documentation [says](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet):

> "each DispatcherServlet has its own
>   WebApplicationContext, which inherits
>   all the beans already defined in the
>   **root WebApplicationContext**. These
>   inherited beans can be overridden in
>   the servlet-specific scope, and you
>   can define new scope-specific beans
>   local to a given servlet instance.

But where do I put this root WebApplicationContext?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have `applicationContext.xml` in the`WEB-INF` directory, and the beans in that config are available to the `spring-servlet.xml` config, its defined using

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

By the way its the `ContextLoaderListener` which is responsible for managing the root context

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```