# Two DispatcherServlets share same ApplicationContext

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I've got two DispatcherServlets. One is configured in web.xml, the other is configured with my implementation of org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer. As I understand by doing this I create two ApplicationContexts. The problem is that they have to share same ApplicationContext.
Initialization looks like this if it helps to understand my question. Web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>web-xml-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/dispatcher-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>web-xml-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/web-test/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

WebApplicationInitializer:

```
public class WebAppInit implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.scan("com.test");
        DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet(context);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet("initializer-dispatcher", servlet);
        dynamic.addMapping("/init-test/*");
    }
}
```

So, is there any way to share one ApplicationContext between dispatchers configured like that?

Comment: Yes.  You can define a root web application context:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521942/spring-root-webapplicationcontext-for-servlet

Comment: @andresoviedo but how can I specify that my DispatcherServlet configured in WebApplicationInitializer should use root context?

Comment: I am posting you the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define a root web application context:

```
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The wiring of the servlet context to the root context is done by default by Spring.